# The above exception (no such table: oauth2_provider_accesstoken) was the direct cause of the following exception:

Tags: python, django

am trying to develop an application with Python3.6 by Django1.10
. trying to test in chrome browser and getting this error massage:-

***The above exception (no such table: oauth2_provider_accesstoken)*** was the direct cause of the following exception:[this the massage in my browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdT6a.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run manage.py migrate to create new tables.